# How to display more posts

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, api

I am receiving a JSON Object which contains some posts from a WordPress account, but I am getting only around 15 posts, what should I do to get more than that amount ?

the JSON looks like this

```
{
 ID: 4164,
 title: "24 Horas Non-Stop con Marco Carola",
 status: "publish",
 type: "post",
 author: {
  ID: 11,
  username: "VIlma Quiros",
  name: "VIlma Quiros",
  first_name: "VIlma",
  last_name: "Quiros",
  nickname: "VIlma Quiros",
  slug: "vilma-quiros",
  URL: "",
  avatar: "",
  description: "",
  registered: "2015-04-16T07:04:04+00:00",
  meta: {
   links: {
   self: "http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/users/11",
   archives: "http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/users/11/posts"
  }
 }
},
content: "<p class="p2"><a href="http://urbanetradio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/PRUEBA-1.png"</p> <p><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AV6nAmjDynE" width="750" height="422" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></p> ",
parent: null,
link: "http://urbanetradio.com/24-horas-non-stop-con-marco-carola/",
date: "2015-05-08T18:42:33",
modified: "2015-05-08T20:20:10",
format: "standard",
slug: "24-horas-non-stop-con-marco-carola",
guid: "http://urbanetradio.com/?p=4164",
excerpt: "<p>El pasado fin de semana, Marco Carola dio un show maratónico en el Festival Sunwaves 2015 al mezclar por no menos de 24 horas seguidas. &#8230;</p> ",
menu_order: 0,
comment_status: "closed",
ping_status: "open",
sticky: false,
date_tz: "America/Costa_Rica",
date_gmt: "2015-05-09T00:42:33",
modified_tz: "America/Costa_Rica",
modified_gmt: "2015-05-09T02:20:10",
...
```

i am sending a get request to `http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts`

here the docs for the API http://wp-api.org/

and I can't see in that JSON which is way bigger than the above, any kind of property/attribute mentioning about post increasing.

Comment: Which request gives you this JSON in return?

Comment: sorry, I am sending a get to ```http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts```

Comment: It should probably be http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=30 if you want to retrieve 30 posts for instance.  It doesn't seem to work in your case, results seem to stay the same no matter what params you pass. Do you have wp-json properly configured? Otherwise, I would suggest JSON API, which worked for me perfectly ... https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display more posts using `?filter[posts_per_page]=30`

**EDIT:**
It does seem like this doesn't work for you (not even the example provided in the docs which should work)

```
http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=8&filter[order]=ASC
```

so I am assuming you have problems with the configuration somehow.

If this won't work for you even after you try to reconfig, I will suggest an alternative: [JSON API plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/), which worked for me perfectly and will most likely for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are sending a GET request to /sites/$site/posts/ endpoint, to get the JSON.  you can send a query parameter asking for the number of posts you want along with url

```
?number=20
```

the maximum number of posts that can be retrieved is limited to 100.

https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1.1/get/sites/%24site/posts/

Comment: if you check the documentation at wp-api.org there are two query params available posts_per_page & showposts, which you can use to get the required number of posts.

[http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=1] (http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=1)

[http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts?filter[showposts]=1] (http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts?filter[showposts]=1)

when i tried i am getting 403 Forbidden.

Comment: why are you getting that 403 ?

Comment: I am not sure why i am getting a 403.  may be you could check the logs.  

I tried the same with http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=10 .  Change the value for filter[posts_per_page] to  20 and you will get 20 posts